# Hero image not showing up despite I (../image folder/imagename.jpg)

Tags: html, css

Need some help !

Im trying to put a hero image onto my background home page, but its failing on me. the images is in a separate folder from the css therefore I used the (../). It is still unsuccessful. I am at a beginner level.

```
hero-image{

    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../images/graduate.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}   

<!Doctype>
<html>
    <head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="css/home.css"></link>
    <title>Home</title> 
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "hamburger" class = "sidenav">
            <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closenav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="my_story.html">My Story</a>
            <a href="career.html">Career</a>
            <a href="education.html">Education</a>
            <a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <!<img alt="icon"src="images/icon.png">
        </div>  
            
        <span style="font-size:30px; Cursor:pointer" onclick="opennav()">&#9776;</span>     
        
        <script>
            function opennav(){doctype.getElementById("hamburger").style.display="block"; 
            function closenav(){doctype.getElementById("hamburger").style.display="none";
        </script>
        
        <div class="hero-image">
            <div class="hero-text">
                <h1>The Mindful Hustle</h1>
            </div>
        </div>  
        
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using a Web server or Localhost on your machine. You do not need ../images/graduate.jpg.

Instead just use this images/graduate.jpg or /images/graduate.jpg

Comment: Please provide the following information: 1. What is the folder structure , where is the html file and where is the hero image? 2. What is the url you see when this html page is opened ? 3. How are you launching the page , local server / deployed online / just viewing a static page.

Answer (score 1):

End of line 3: `url(../images/graduate.jpg);`, change to `url(/images/graduate.jpg);`.

Answer (score 0):

Initially remove linear gradient only use image url, to be sure that gradient isn't hiding the image or something.

```
background-image:url(../images/graduate.jpg);
```

and
background-image:url(http://clipart-library.com/images/di45bnqMT.jpg);

This is to ensure that the issue is only with the path and nothing else.

If both of the above works then try this:

```
background-image:url(../images/graduate.jpg),
linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
```

Comment: Hi Vipul, i'm not sure what you mean by file structure ? I am saving all the file locally . What I've done is I created 1 folder for all css, 1folder for all images and 1 folder for all html. they are all saved in the same folder directory.  the URL I see is file:///C:/Users/Jude/Documents/Digital%20CV/home.html . I simply launch the page by simply clicking on the html folder (Chrome html document) and refresh each time I make a change to the html and css on Notepad ++. I made the changes suggested, its still unsuccessful. Would you suggest any other way to the way i am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve it. I had to "div."  at CSS :

```
div.hero-image{ background-image:(..url/images/graduate.jpg)}
```